# Adding html edit button to each new row of table with JS

Tags: javascript

I have a form that lets users add new rows to a table using JS:

```
       //adds a new account row
        if (tit.innerHTML === "Add Account"){
          var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
          var row = table.insertRow(0);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      
  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_type").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_price").value;
}
```

I want to also add an edit button to each new row that is created, with a specified td class.

```
<td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
```

I tried declaring a var cell3 and putting cell3.innerHTML = "the code above" which did nothing. I also tried doing it with =+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a template cell, then clone it to add to each row with the chosen class or an empty cell if the row doesn't have the class (could also use colspan on the last cell in the row to widen those that don't get an edit button). E.g.

```js
function addButtons() {
  let cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.classList.add('edtbutton');
  cell.innerHTML = '<button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button>';
  document.querySelectorAll('#t0 tr').forEach(row => {
    if (row.classList.contains('editableRow')) {
      row.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true));
    } else {
      row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    }
  });
}

function sayedit(){
  console.log('edit me…');
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
tr.editableRow {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<table id="t0">
  <tr><td>not editable
  <tr class="editableRow"><td>cell
  <tr class="editableRow"><td>cell
  <tr class="editableRow"><td>cell
</table>

<button onclick="addButtons()">Add buttons</button>
```

Comment: I'll test it out a bit more and see if I can get it to work. One problem is that tr's are added by form input and don't have a tr class. Also for simplicity I want the buttons to always be there. (I'd prefer to show/hide them using a separate function.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Define this function

```
let fragmentFromString = function (strHTML) {
  return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strHTML);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
if (tit.innerHTML === "Add Account"){
          var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
          var row = table.insertRow(0);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_type").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("modal_price").value;
  let button = '<td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>'
  cell3.appendChild(fragmentFromString(button));
}
```

Comment: I played around with it a little but sadly couldn't get it working. I placed the first code snippet outside the function, and added what you mentioned in the second snippet.